# View controller not presenting if already visible

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-universal-links

I'm trying to present a view controller from my AppDelegate (for universal links). I have it presenting the view controller the first time around, but if the view controller is already showing, it doesn't re-present it.

On the view controller, I just print the `number` that I pass to the view controller (below). I get the `number` from a parameter in the universal link, e.g. `https://mywebsite.com/{number}`.

Here is my code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

guard let root = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController else {
    return
}

guard let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as? MyViewController else {
    return
}

// This is a number I pass to the controller
vc.number = number

if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .automatic
} else {
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
}

vc.layoutType = MyViewController.LayoutType.normal

root.present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

So again, when I present this view controller the first time, it works as normal. But if the view controller is already showing, it doesn't re-present it (with a different `number` value, meaning the view controller doesn't show the correct number).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If controller is already present, then why you want to re-present it ? Just fire notification and update value with correct number.

Comment: @VRAwesome How can I tell if the controller is already open? I tried `if (self.isViewLoaded && self.view.window != nil)` but it's true no matter what.